# How to convert an escape sequence to a human-readable keystroke?

Tags: terminal, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, escape-characters

I am looking for a Linux command, or a zsh command, or at least an online service that given:

- an escape sequence like "^[^[[1~", "\M-C\M-^X" or "^[[1;5F" (these are not made up, but output from my `bindkey`)
- and my setup (PC keyboard, Konsole terminal and any other info that can have effect on generation of escape sequences)

can show me a corresponding keystroke or their combination. Bonus points if it can explain colors etc, but my main interest is keyboard shortcuts.

Context: I am learning zsh key bindings that are heavily customized in [zsh4humans](https://github.com/romkatv/zsh4humans) (thus most of online zsh cheatsheets do not apply). I know that `bindkey` can show me a list of all shortcuts, and `info zsh <widget name>` provides a widget's meaning. I know that I can convert a keystroke to an escape sequence myself using `showkey -a` (but ofc it uses the caret notation that may not match a notation shown by zsh). So, basically I'm looking for a command that performs an opposite function of `showkey`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `infocmp`?

Comment: Not really. `infocmp` simply prints a table of terminfo. I still need to do the work of matching these entries with a specific escape sequence, like the examples in my question. This is not feasible with dozens of key bindings, when they are more complicated then ^K. So, I need a command to which I can feed a (combined) escape sequence

Comment: In that case you're probably looking at some custom code

Comment: This related question is an example of manual work that I'd like to automate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108009/weird-escape-sequence?rq=1 I've tried asking ChatGPT as well - with rather poor results.

Comment: The sequences are dependent on your terminal emulator - gnome-terminal, xterm, konsole, putty, urxvt etc. There are some basic rules, Alt typically prepends an escape (Meta used to set the eighth-bit before Unicode broke that). Function style keys can vary greatly but the numbers and trailing tilde are common. ABCD are common for the cursors and the F example is probably related. Zsh key bindings can aslo entail sequences of keys. Ctrl-X followed by other keys are common as are sequences in vi-mode such as `bindkey -a -s 'cw' 'dwi'` The `describe-key-briefly` widget can be useful.